# How can I get GMT timezone current time in jmeter

Tags: datetime, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to get GMT +7 time into jmeter. I tried following but it seems not GMT.

```
    ${__time(dd/MM/yyyy,)}
    ${__time(hh:mm a,)}
    ${__time(dd-mmm-yyyy HHmmss)}
    ${__javaScript(new Date().getTime();)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) class documentation

[image: SimpleDateFormat JMeter Timestamp]

So you can modify pattern of JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) according to your requirement. Examples:

[image: JMeter Timezone Examples]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post for more detailed information on __time() and other JMeter Functions.